# Navigation properties do not get refreshed

Tags: javascript, caching, breeze

I have a `Home` entity that I send from my server down to my clients.

```
public Home {
   public HomeId {get;set;}
   public String Address {get; set;}
   public ICollection<Room> Rooms{ get; set;}
}
```

All data management on the client side is handled by BreezeJs.

My web application is multiuser. Whenever a user updates a `Home` entity, the server notifies all interested clients using SignalR. 
When a client is notified, it runs the following query to refresh its cache:

```
function refresh(homeId) {
    var query = entityQuery.from('Homes')
                   .withParameters({ homeId: homeId });

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
                  .fail(queryfailed);

    function queryfailed(data) {
        // error
    }
}
```

The server side controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public Home Homes(int homeId)
    {
        var home = _context.Context.Homes
                           .Include(t => t.Rooms)
                           .FirstOrDefault(t => t.HomeId == homeId);
        return home;
    }
```

**Problem**

When a `Home` entity is refreshed, all properties get the new values from the server but not the navigation properties. If a user adds/removes a `Room` to/from a given `House` then the related `Rooms` entities in cache don't get refreshed although the json data looks fine and contains the added/removed `Room` entities.

**Questions**

Is there a simple way to tell Breeze to update the `Home` and all its navigation properties?
Ideally, I would like to do this without clearing the cache as explained [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/entitymanager-and-caching) to avoid some flickering on my UI.

**Update I**

I tried expanding my query to include `Rooms` by

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Homes')
                       .withParameters({ homeId: homeId })
                       .expand("Rooms");
```

Still the same issue, the json data contains the changes made by other clients but are not reflected on the local entities

**Update II**

I managed to get the changes to propagate to clients using `expand`. However, changes get propagated only when `Rooms` are added but not when they are removed.

Comment: Why not just use .expand() on the navigation properties you want to refresh?  Automatically refreshing all navigation properties could get REALLY messy fast, especially on complex object graphs.

Comment: I tried using expand but it did not work, the navigation property did not get updated

Comment: Did those navigation properties have changes when the results were coming back in?

Comment: Yes, they do. The changes I needed are correctly returned from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, my guess is that you are dealing with "rooms' being added and removed from one "house" by one client and these updates not being correctly refreshed on another client with the same "house".

If this is the case, the reason is that the breeze client is able to determine which "rooms" have been added to a house by the other client but it can't determine which rooms have been moved or removed unless you also requery the rooms.

To clarify, imagine if Room 1 is moved from House 1 to House 2 by Client A.  Client B still has House 1 containing Room 1.  When Client B requeries House 1 (with an Include) it will return no rooms, but breeze will NOT remove Room1 from House 1 because it doesn't know where it moved to.  If you were to requery either Room1 or House 2 with an "Rooms" include, then breeze would have sufficient information to "move" the room.

So one approach you could follow would be to simply *detach* "all" rooms associated with a specific house before "refreshing" the house.  You would "lose" any houses that had been moved to another house but these would presumably be refetched by a refresh of that house.

Not sure how clear this is, but...

Comment: You guesses right, what I am aiming for is to get client changes propagate to other clients. Your suggested solution is good but no ideal as I have to detach some 'rooms' before the query completes, this will make the UI flicker after adding the new rooms again

Comment: If you refresh the other house ( that the room moved to) with an expand, this will also cause the correct behavior and you shouldn't get the flicker.

Comment: Agree. The page flickers when removing all rooms then adding newly fetched rooms from the same house